# OrmLite: check if CreateOrUpdate did change any values

Tags: android, ormlite

Is there a way, without building a custom SQL statement, to check if OrmLite's CreateOrUpdate call did actually change any values in the database or not?

`Dao.CreateOrUpdateStatus.getNumLinesChanged()` returns the rows affected value, so the result is 1 also if the object that was updated did not change at all.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Are you trying to test whether or not the DB update worked?

Comment: No, whether it changed any values: if I did an update with the same values that were already in the row, or if the update changed something.

Comment: Oh.   You could do an update with conditionals (`UPDATE ... WHERE field != newValue ...`) but that would not work with `createOrUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I added the below methods to my class, and I call one of these methods in every setXXX method.

```
private boolean objectChanged = false;

private void checkChanged(Object ob1, Object ob2) {
    if (ob1 == null && ob2 == null) {
        // both null = same, do nothing
        return;
    } else if (ob1 == null || ob2 == null) {
        // only one null
        objectChanged = true;
    } else if (ob2.equals(ob1)) {
        // same, do nothing
        return;
    } else {
        objectChanged = true;
    }
}

private void checkChanged(int int1, int int2) {
    if (int1 != int2) {
        objectChanged = true;
    }
}
```

It is a solution that works, but I do not like it. If anyone has a better solution, without making an extra database call, let me know.

Comment: Yeah I don't see how ORMLite can help here.  There aren't two objects to compare unless you mean the internal object cache which isn't on by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: (Payments Table example)

```
try {
            final Dao paymentsTable = getHelper().getPaymentsTable();
            Dao.CreateOrUpdateStatus changedRows = paymentsTable.createOrUpdate(_payments);
            Log.e("WAS CREATED",  Boolean.toString(changedRows.isCreated()) );
            Log.e("WAS UPDATED",  Boolean.toString(changedRows.isUpdated()) );
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```